# Facebook JSON string handling in C# MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I trying to get the pictures along with likes from my Facebook fan page in MVC application. I am using Facebook C# SDK for this purpose. following is the code which returns the result in a JSON format.

```
var client = new FacebookClient();                
client.AppId= "your_access_token";
client.AppSecret = "your_App_Secret";
client.AccessToken = "your_access_token";
dynamic data= client.Get("FanPageName?fields=id,name,photos{name,source,likes.summary(true).filter(stream)}");
```

the above code returns an JSON and I stored it in a dynamic object named data. Now I want to iterate this JSON so that I can store the data in the database for further working.

I am confused here on how to iterate this dynamic object.

Comment: whats the json looks like? iterate on what?

Comment: Paste the Json string into your code window as C# classes (Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes) and then deserialise JSON into those classes.

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253133/how-do-i-create-a-dynamically-typed-c-sharp-iterator-block

Comment: the JSON format is `{"id":"some id","name":"some name","photos":{"data":[{"source":"some source", "likes":{"data":[{.......... "total_count":211354}]}}]}}` and i wan to iterate the this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the info about the photos is as simple as doing:

```
foreach(dynamic photo in data.photos.data) {
   var url = photo.source.Value; // returns a string type
   var likes = ((IEnumerable)photo.likes.data).Cast<dynamic>()
        .Sum(x => x.total_count);
}
```

Take note of the Linq part as I was not sure if the `likes.data` returns an array with more than one item, it doesn't show in your comment. Although it doesn't make sense to have more than one item as a photo should (IMO) only have "one total count". If its guaranteed that it returns only one item then you can simply do a:

```
photo.likes.data[0].total_count.Value
```

But then again taking the Linq approach is the safer one.